# JIRA Rest API - getting the list of all Projects and all issues within each project

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

what is the correct https link to get JSON data for all the projects at once?

the current link to our dashboard is like this:

https://company.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Would like to get all of the projects then use another https call to get all the issues for all the projects. Then after that of course look at assignees etc etc. Looking to collect this data to put into an iOS app for R&D purposes.

I am coming at this blind but I have no idea if I also need someone to set up permissions to do this or something. Never used this API before so just doing some discovery here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to speak with the API :)
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: yeah i have been looking at it. https://mycompany.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/project/  gives me a "server not found" page. However if i try the general jira https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/project/ it seems to work. what am I missing?

Comment: check that, it looks like it works now???? What would cause it to say "Server not found" then no problem later??

Comment: your base path should be
https://company.atlassian.net/ (with https)

Comment: it was earlier when i got a 'server not found'. Well its working now. hopefully no more issues :)